# Python crashes as soon as loading Jupyter Notebook or Anaconda Navigator

Tags: windows, windows-10, python, crash

0

I am using Anaconda and python crashes during startup.

I have re-installed Anaconda. Tried 3.6 and 3.7 both. I updated conda using anaconda prompt. I upgraded all the libraries.

Crash Log:

```
Faulting application name: python.exe, version: 3.6.5150.1013, time stamp: 0x5abd3210
Faulting module name: DbgHelp.dll_unloaded, version: 10.0.16299.15, time stamp: 0x38fe792a
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000010d3f9
Faulting process id: 0x3be4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d4dfde1697a6c8
Faulting application path: C:\Users\Infinitowork\Anaconda3\python.exe
Faulting module path: DbgHelp.dll
Report Id: f9b50fa1-049a-4d85-9279-8e38fbf2a7d7
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I expected it to open but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Install any available windows update. Many service packs and other patches replace or update some of the hundreds of Microsoft distributed DLL files on your computer. The `dbghelp.dll` file could be included in one of those updates.